# How to create a Mongoid document from JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid

I'm trying to build a **Mongoid** document from a *JSON* string. I'm guessing it can be done this way:

```
SomeDocumentClass.new(JSON.parse(json_string))
```

But is there a more convenient or straight through way to do it?. Maybe a **Mongoid** method?.

Best,

Comment: If your json file is created by `mongoexport` command, you can use `mongoimport` to import json data to mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage above is a good example of composition of functions and associated functionality.  It is very clear, and you don't need anything more.  If you have many of these calls, you can simply create your own class function like the following.

```
class SomeDocumentClass
  def self.new_from_json(json_string)
     self.new(JSON.parse(json_string)
  end
end
```

Usage

```
SomeDocumentClass.new_from_json(json_string)
```

Or you can create your own global function for less typing and more obscurity. But IMHO, this all smells of bike shedding or yak shaving. Please just move ahead to a real blocking problem.